# Want to change button position on change of condition in Constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

> Here, is my layout

[image]

> I know how to design it using constraint layout and also adding constraint at runtime.
>
> In below image, I want to change selected icon at runtime means if I on switch both left icon should be at right side and both right icon should be at left.
>
> If I swtich off then reverse case should happen.

Now, I know we can do this using runtime constraint but I only want to know is it possible to do it in layout(xml) file directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement **dataBinding** is possible to pass parameters to the XML and make your layout to behave depending of those parameters. So for example you pass a **boolean** to the xml and on the element constraint you can define a different behavior like:

```
<layout>
    <data>
      <variable name="example" type="Boolean"/>
    </data>

    <Constraint element
         top_constraint="@{(example) ? "constraint_a" : "constraint_b"}
    />
</layout>
```

So instead of changing all the layout programatically you set the constraints according to a single boolean value.

You can get a better understanding of dataBinding here [Android Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)